# excel - group by and sum, then group by and average - pivot table of pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, powerquery

For the below table, I am first looking to sum values by name and date.  Then using that result data looking to take the average of value, grouped by name, for each month.

It seems like I want to take a take a pivot table of a pivot table.  I am trying to use powerpivot although I am open to ideas.

Does anyone know how to do this?

| date | value | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/29/23 | 50 | stephen |
| 12/29/23 | 20 | bob |
| 12/29/23 | 30 | tom |
| 12/28/23 | 5 | stephen |
| 12/28/23 | 7 | bob |
| 12/28/23 | 3 | tom |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted, then this should work as expected :*

• Using `GROUPBY()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _GroupBySum, GROUPBY(HSTACK(B3:B8,D3:D8),C3:C8,SUM,0,0),
     _CombineMonthName, HSTACK(TEXT(TAKE(_GroupBySum,,1),"mmm"),INDEX(_GroupBySum,,2)),
     _Output, GROUPBY(_CombineMonthName,TAKE(_GroupBySum,,-1),AVERAGE,0,0),
     VSTACK({"Month","Name","Values"},_Output))
```

---

Or,

• Using `PIVOTBY()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _PivotBySum, PIVOTBY(HSTACK(B3:B8,D3:D8),,C3:C8,SUM,0,0),
     _CombineMonthName, HSTACK(TEXT(TAKE(_PivotBySum,,1),"mmm"),INDEX(_PivotBySum,,2)),
     _Output, PIVOTBY(_CombineMonthName,,TAKE(_PivotBySum,,-1),AVERAGE,0,0),
     VSTACK({"Month","Name","Values"},_Output))
```

---

**Note:** Both the functions `GROUPBY()` & `PIVOTBY()` are available in `MS365` for Beta Users.

---

Also I had prefer using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>. To achieve this using the said procedure, follow this simple steps using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> window `UI`:

[image]

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"date", type date}, {"value", Int64.Type}, {"name", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"date", "name"}, {{"Value", each List.Sum([value]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Extracted Month Name" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", {{"date", each Date.MonthName(_), type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Extracted Month Name", {"date", "name"}, {{"Values", each List.Average([Value]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows1",{{"name", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Updated with Months as headers.

[image]

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"date", type date}, {"value", Int64.Type}, {"name", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Changed Type", {{"value", null}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Replaced Errors", each [value] <> null and [value] <> ""),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"date", "name"}, {{"Value", each List.Sum([value]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Extracted Month Name" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", {{"date", each Date.MonthName(_), type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Extracted Month Name", List.Distinct(#"Extracted Month Name"[date]), "date", "Value", List.Average)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

---

Comment: is all this considered power pivot?

Comment: No, first two methods uses formulas while the last one is using `Power Query`. Posted as an alternative since as per your OP --> _"I am trying to use powerpivot **although I am open to ideas**."_

Comment: I am trying the power query way.  I get invalid cell value '#N/A'.  is there a way to have this ignore those values?

Comment: @solarissf so you have cells which shows as `#N/A` is that so, if yes then you can replace them as null or 0 to evaluate. or remove nulls

Comment: @solarissf after the change type step add these two steps: `#"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Changed Type", {{"value", null}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Replaced Errors", each [value] <> null and [value] <> ""),`

Comment: @solarissf here is a copy of the **[Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckgIAi8pp92MhlYtl?e=KVyM7N)** you can download to check for yourself

Comment: thank you!  so I have it working but a couple questions...  1. how do I change around the layout? so for example the filedate is all in first column... I have the months to be the headers.  2. what language is that, that you wrote to create that query? in the advanced editor.  I would like to google to learn more about how to write more

Comment: You want the month as headers like in pivot table yes that is also possible, i will update that in the answer. Its called Power Query -- M Code (Language). and here is a link you might like to go through --> **[Power Query](https://powerquery.microsoft.com/en-us/)**

Comment: @solarissf you can download the excel again to see the updated ones. **[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckgIAi8pp92MhlYtl?e=xdcqsE)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256422/discussion-between-solarissf-and-mayukh-bhattacharya).

Comment: @solarissf are you able to resolve it now?